# Getting value from 1st drop down list jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have my 1st drop down list **id="bfnsCode"**, I want to use that value to my next drop down list id="taxtCode" to be able to show new set of values based on the 1st drop down. here is my code:

```
<div class="BIR" style="display: none;">
            <div>
            <label style="font-size: 17px;">BIR-Form Number</label><br>         
                <select name="bfnsCode" id="bfnsCode" class="sel" style="width: 245px; margin-left: 0;">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <%
                        TblBIRFormNoDAO birdao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblBIRFormNo.class);

                        HttpSession live = request.getSession(true);
                        TblUserInformation user = (TblUserInformation) live.getAttribute("user");

                        List<TblBIRFormNo> birtypelist =  null;                     

                        if(user.getRcoCode() != null){
                            birtypelist =birdao.getAllBirFormNumber();
                        }else{

                        }

                        String birtypeoptions = "";

                        if( birtypelist!=null) {
                            if( birtypelist.size()>0 ) {
                            for(int i=0; i<birtypelist.size();i++) {
                            TblBIRFormNo taxtype = (TblBIRFormNo) birtypelist.get(i);
                            birtypeoptions += "<option value='"+taxtype.getBfnsCode()+"'>"+taxtype.getBfnsCode()+"</option>";                                       
                            taxtype = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        birdao = null;
                        birtypelist = null;
                        %>
                        <%=birtypeoptions%>

                </select>   
            <br><br>
            <label style="font-size: 17px;">Tax Type</label><br>            
                <select name="taxtCode" id="taxtCode" class="sel" style="margin-left: 0;">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <%
                        TblTaxTypeDAO taxdao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblTaxType.class);

                        List<TblTaxType> taxtypelist =  null;

                        String tax = request.getParameter("bfnsCode");
                        Debugger.print("test : "+tax);

                        if(tax != null){
                            taxtypelist = taxdao.findAlltaxtCode(tax);
                        }else{
                            taxtypelist = taxdao.getAllTaxTypes();
                        }

                        String taxtypeoptions = "";

                        if( taxtypelist!=null) {
                            if( taxtypelist.size()>0 ) {
                            for(int i=0; i<taxtypelist.size();i++) {
                            TblTaxType taxtype = (TblTaxType) taxtypelist.get(i);
                            taxtypeoptions += "<option value='"+taxtype.getTaxtCode()+"'>"+taxtype.getTaxtCode()+"</option>";                                       
                            taxtype = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        taxdao = null;
                        taxtypelist = null;
                        %>
                        <%=taxtypeoptions%>         

                </select>
```

As you can see, I call the value using **request.getParameter("bfnsCode")** in drop down tax but it gives me a null value.

**ListBIRFormNo.java**(servlet for **c:forEach**)

```
public class ListBIRFormNo extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<TblBIRFormNo> birtypelist;

public List<TblBIRFormNo> getTblBIRFormNo() {
    return birtypelist;
}
public void setTblBIRFormNo(List<TblBIRFormNo> birtypelist) {
    this.birtypelist = birtypelist;
}
private HttpServletRequest request;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    this.request = request;
}

public String execute(){
    Debugger.border();
    try{
        TblBIRFormNoDAO birdao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblBIRFormNo.class);

        HttpSession live = request.getSession(true);
        TblUserInformation user = (TblUserInformation) live.getAttribute("user");

        if(user.getRcoCode() != null){
            birtypelist =birdao.getAllBirFormNumber();          
        }else{
            //no-op
        }

        //expose 'birtypelist' as an attribute
        request.setAttribute("birtypelist", birtypelist); 

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Debugger.print(" EXCEPTION :"+e.getStackTrace());
        Debugger.endDebug(this.getClass().toString());
        Debugger.border();
    }
    Debugger.border();
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Use servlets and store the parameters in request attributes to render in the next view jsp.

Comment: Is it possible just using single form? these are only divs inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the request processing lifecycle.  The only way for `request.getParameter("bfnsCode")` to have a non-null value is if a parameter called `bfnsCode` was sent with the *current* request.  That's not the case you have here (as far as I can tell), as all of your code executes within the context of a single request.  So yes, `bfnsCode` will be null at the time you check for it.

If you want one select box to respond to another within the same page, that is something that is usually/best accomplished with JavaScript.  You'd want an `onchange` or `onkeyup` (or both) event handler on the first `<select>` box, and you'd want to implement it so that it gets the value from the first box and then uses it to update the second box (either by making an AJAX call to load in the relevant data, or by loading in the correct set of data from some cache that you set up with the page).  This sounds more complicated than it actually is (especially if you are using a JavaScript framework like jQuery), but you cannot solve the problem using purely server-side code as your current approach does.

Please consider refactoring your implementation so that it doesn't embed Java code directly inside of a JSP page.  You can move the business logic related to checking for a user and querying for the list of forms to a `Servlet` implementation (or equivalent Servlet-like construct provided by Struts; an `Action` I believe it is), and then use a `<c:forEach>` tag to append options to your `<select>` element (i.e. what Sotirios said in his comment).

For example, in your `Servlet`/`Action` code you could set up `birtypelist` as you are currently, and then do:

```
if(user.getRcoCode() != null){
    birtypelist =birdao.getAllBirFormNumber();
}else{
    //no-op
}

//expose 'birtypelist' as an attribute
request.setAttribute("birtypelist", birtypelist);
```

...and then in your JSP page, you can use:

```
<select name="bfnsCode" id="bfnsCode" class="sel" style="width: 245px; margin-left: 0;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <c:forEach var="taxtype" items="${birtypelist}">
        <option value="${taxType.bfnsCode}">${taxType.bfnsCode}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

That will give comparable results to the programmatic approach that you currently have.

Comment: Yeah, I saw something that I should do this, I'm just hoping maybe there's an easier way. Thanks for letting me know what I must do.

Comment: Yeah this is what I want but my list is based on my database, I can't do it in static way.

Comment: @RMsplace - Right, so you can either use an AJAX call to fetch the data when the first box changes, or (if your database is small) you can set up something similar to the `data` array in the JSFiddle by using your JSP to output your information as JSON.

Comment: I would like to use the `<:forEach>` tag. Can you lead me to way how to do that using database?

Comment: @RMsplace - I've updated the answer with an example of how to refactor the code to use a `<c:forEach>` loop.

Comment: Didn't setup a list in servlet before. I'm doing my list by inserting a java code inside jsp.

Comment: Added codes in my post. Kindly check if that's what you meant.